# How to achieve @PrePersist / @PreUpdate with Quarkus' Panache and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-reactive

I would like to automatically persist the usual properties like createdAt/updatedAt and createdBy/updatedBy of my mongoDB base entity. With PostgreSQL I would use the @PrePersist and @PreUpdate annotations to achieve this.

How can I do this with MongoDB?

My BaseEntity:

```
public class BaseEntity extends ReactivePanacheMongoEntity {
    // [...]
    public ZonedDateTime createdAt;
    public ZonedDateTime updatedAt;
    public UUID createdBy;
    public UUID updatedBy;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23420 may help